# WPF Datagrid ComboBoxColumn showing code behind custom class collection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

first of all: I'm fairly new to WPF / XAML.

What I want to achieve:
The MainWindow class contains a custom class A, which itself contains a list of custom class B object. In a datagrid I need a comboboxcolumn which displays the content of the list of class B objects as possible options to choose (TwoWay), while of course showing the currently selected item. The value shown in the combobox is a property of class B.

Code behind looks like this:

```
public partial class MainWindow
{
   private ClassA MyClassAObject {get; set;}
}
```

Class A:

```
class ClassA
{
   public List<ClassB> ClassBContainer {get; set;}
   // some other properties
}
```

Class B:

```
class ClassB
{
   public string Name { get; set;}
   // some other properties
}
```

I'm actually facing this problem now for 5 hours, not finding a solution.

I've tried several approaches, mainly using the `<DataGridComboBoxColumn />` with it's properties (trying to bind values to it), including RelativeSource and "proxy" resources (as I figured out the ComboBoxColumn does not inherit the DataContext, nor the visualtree?).

I've also tried `<DataGridTemplateColumn />` but couldn't get that approach to work either.

I know I should read about MVVM but as this is the last step for my small application to reach a milestone and therefore being more or less finished I keep that for later.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "I know I should read about MVVM but as this is the last step for my small application to reach a milestone and therefore being more or less finished I keep that for later." - Maybe you should reconsider that.

Comment: @Fildor Wow. Thanks.

Comment: I know it sounds stupid. But those 5 hours invested into learning MVVM might have gotten you to a working solution already.